# Media Aggregation

Tags: feeds

I dont know whether the drupal aggregator does media aggregation. I basically want to play audio/video or other multimedia in the aggregator. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate a wee bit? The phrasing is a bit tricky to understand, it's definitely not possible to play audio/video "in the aggregator" as the aggregator is a service that pulls in feeds to the site. Do you mean you want to use the aggregator to automatically create content with attached audio/video media?

Comment: @Clive: Sorry my bad. You are right. I want the aggregator to automatically create content with attached audio/video media.

Comment: So, you want to keep the enclosures from the feeds on other sites in your feed aggregator? That is just what I want to do. Unfortunately, there is no such option in Aggregator so far and all the other modules did not solve this issue.